# can't seem to find the issue with text over image, tried using realtive and absolute positioning on parent element but nothing is working

Tags: html, css

This is my code :

```css
img {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

/* styling text-boxes over my images on potfolio.html*/

.text {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
}

/*^^^^^^ styling text-boxes over my images on portfolio.html^^^^^*/


/* styling images on portfolio.html */

.image {
  float: left;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 1%;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myimages">
  <img class="image image1" alt="image" src="images/image1.jpg" />
  <h1><span class="text hangman">HANGMAN</span></h1>
  <img class="image image2" alt="image" src="images/image2.jpg" />
  <h1><span class="text rpg">RPG GAME</span></h1>
  <img class="image image3" alt="image" src="images/image3.jpg" />
  <h1><span class="text trivia">TRIVIA GAME</span></h1>
  <img class="image image4" alt="image" src="images/image4.jpg" />
  <h1><span class="text rutgers">RUTGERS INFO WIDGET</span></h1>
  <img class="image image5" alt="image" src="images/image5.jpg" />
  <h1><span class="text rps">ROCK PAPER SCISSORS</span></h1>
</div>
```

every time I try position the text, it hasn't worked, I've even tried adding an absolute value and adding a z-index on it so that it would display on the image however i need it to be responsive. so i'm using bootstrap for this one. I've already added some col-md-8 on it so the content stays inside it. I, however, am unable to depict what is going on with my code.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `img` and `.text` miss a common parent to sit in

I'll use the `<div class="game">` Divisor element:

```css
.mygames {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.game {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 0 1 33.333%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 30vh;
}
.game .image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.game .text {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mygames">
  <div class="game">
    <img class="image" alt="image" src="//placehold.it/200x100/0bf" />
    <h1 class="text"><span>HANGMAN</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="game">
    <img class="image" alt="image" src="//placehold.it/200x100/f0b" />
    <h1 class="text"><span>RPG GAME</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="game">
    <img class="image" alt="image" src="//placehold.it/200x100/0fb" />
    <h1 class="text"><span>TRIVIA GAME</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="game">
    <img class="image" alt="image" src="//placehold.it/200x100/fb0" />
    <h1 class="text"><span>RUTGERS INFO WIDGET</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="game">
    <img class="image" alt="image" src="//placehold.it/200x100/bf0" />
    <h1 class="text"><span>ROCK PAPER SCISSORS</span></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```